# Mongoose find settings eg. if location is all display all results not Location: "all"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose for a while but I don't know how to make the find results easier. I use express and when the location is "ALL" I want to get all results, not Location: "ALL". Any ideas guys how can I do that?

```
    Property.find({ 'Location.City': request.params.location }, function(err, allProperties) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(Date() + " - ERROR Occured: " + err);
            }
            else {
                response.render("propertiesView", { properties: allProperties, propertiesCount: allProperties.length, moment: moment });
            }

        })
        .skip(request.params.page * 10)
        .limit(10)
        .sort({ PostDate: -1 });
```

Comment: why dont add a condition ? if(request.params.location == 'ALL') { //use Property.find({}) } else { //use your current code }

Comment: I tried that but when I have lot of variables it gets insane. I was thinking that I can do something much easier. I tried Location: "" but it considers as a space.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be a solution? To push to a variable if is not equal to "ALL" or is another one easier than this one?

```
// Set Search settings
    var searchSettings = {};


if (request.params.location != "ALL") {
    var location = { 'Location.City': request.params.location };

    searchSettings.push(location);

}

Property.find(searchSettings, function(err, allProperties) {
        if (err) { console.log(Date() + " - ERROR Occured: " + err); }
        else {
            response.render("propertiesView", { properties: allProperties, propertiesCount: allProperties.length, moment: moment });
        }
    });
```